# is thread switching possible during request processing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, threadstatic

I have an MVC application, which also uses EF and a simple Unit of work pattern implementation.
Here's what my `UnitOfWork` looks like:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static UnitOfWork _current;

    private MyContext _context;

    public static UnitOfWork Current
    {
        get { return _current; }
    }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
         _current = this;
    }

    public MyContext GetContext()
    {
        if(_context == null)
            _context = new MyContext();

        return _context;
    }

    public int Commit()
    {
        return _context == null ? 0 : _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _current = null;

        if(_context != null)
            _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I have a generic repository which encapsulates common db operations:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TEntityKey> where TEntity : class
{
    private MyContext _context;

    private MyContext Context
    {
        get { return _context ?? (_context = UnitOfWork.Current.GetContext()); }
    }

    public void Add(TEntity newEntity)
    {
       _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(newEntity);
    }

    //Other methods...
}
```

How it is used:

```
using(var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
{
    _repository.Add(newEntity);
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

So, the question is if it is possible, that the MVC framework internally switches threads while processing a request. Since the current `UnitOfWork` is thread static, such a switch will cause a `NullReferenceException` when calling `UnitOfWork.Current` (please correct if I'm not right).

Comment: I would imagine that each request to a controller method gets a single thread with which it fulfills the entire request, unless you do something like `ThreadPool`, `Task<T>` or `async`.  What does `MyContext` do?

Comment: You should fix your code in 4th line of `UnitOfWOrk`

Comment: `MyContext` represents the db, it is a simple class derived from EF's `DbContext`.

Comment: ASP.NET _loves_ thread-switching, yummy sneaky sudden thread-switching. Specially if you build async stuff. How about using HttpContext.Items instead?

Comment: It has just `DbSet`'s of the entities. I don't have any parallel code (and this code works as well), I meant exactly "internal" switches.

Comment: Simon, thank you! Will consider this.

Comment: If Microsoft does not guarantee not to switch threads, then you should assume that threads are switched whenever Microsoft feels like it. And what about third party code (HttpModule, etc)?

Comment: John, thanks, I see I should not rely on `ThreadStatic`